# jQuery not looping through divs with dynamic names

Tags: jquery, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying to loop through an array of 'floors', make a button for each and a container for 'room' divs, then go through the containers and populate with 'rooms'. Essentially I want to create a bunch of divs from an array, then a bunch of divs inside those from arrays.

As I create the containers I give them an incremental id (the containers are roomPref; yep, I realise there's something called roomContainer, that's incidental for now):

```
$.each(floors, function(index, value)
{
    $(document.getElementsByClassName("floorPref")).append('<a>' + value + '</a> <div class="roomContainer"> <div class="roomPref" id="roomPref'+value+'"> </div> </div>');
});
```

I then try to iterate through by id and populate with rooms, but for whatever reason it doesn't work:

```
$.each(floors, function(index1, value1)
{
    $.each(rooms, function(index2, value2)
    {
        $(document.getElementById('roomPrefB'+value1)).append('<a>' + value2 + '</a>');
    });
});
```

For the moment I'm using fake arrays for testing, as follows:

```
var floors = [];
for(i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    floors[i] = "B";
    floors[i] += i+1;
}
var rooms = [];
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    rooms[i] = i+1;
}
```

It may be useful to know that appending to a named element "roomPrefB1" does work, and appending to all elements by fetching by class name populates all of them, which leads me to believe it could be a problem with the way I'm writing the dynamic name 'roomPrefB'+value1, except I've tried several ways and this one does seem right.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Show your `html` too..

Comment: "I then try to iterate" "jquery not finding"  - `$(document.getElementById('roomPrefB'+value1))` is not jquery - it's javascript that can't find the 'roomPrefB1'.  Try changing this to `$("#roomPrefB" + value1)`

Comment: Out of curiosity, I did and it has the same effect - is there an advantage to the jQuery approach?

Comment: Yeah- as you found this wasn't the issue.    Generally don't mix javascript commands like 'getElementById' with jquery commands like `#` - it looks clunky and it's harder to work with.   `#id` and `.class` are much easier to work with.

Comment: I recommend you delete the question so you don't get any/too many downvotes

Comment: is there any perfoirmance benefit doing `$(document.getElementsByClassName("floorPref"))` rather than `$('.floorPref')` and also for the id one?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm an idiot. The values in the "floors" array are Bx, and I'm trying to append them like they're x. Who saw that coming, no prizes.

Comment: Just found that via a fiddle.  You're trying to find "roomPrefBB11" which doesn't exist.